Celery Worker doesn't find the task
I use the worker in conjunction with beats and beats finds everything perfectly, but as soon as beat passes the task to the worker, an error pops up: KeyError: 'tasks.cache_popular_posts'
all information:
Did you remember to import the module containing this task?
Or maybe you're using relative imports?

Please see
https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/latest/internals/protocol.html
for more information.

The full contents of the message body was:
b'[[], {}, {"callbacks": null, "errbacks": null, "chain": null, "chord": null}]' (77b)

The full contents of the message headers:
{'lang': 'py', 'task': 'tasks.cache_popular_posts', 'id': 'bdaa8c59-8b84-4f79-af1c-7fe34468894d', 'shadow': None, 'eta': None, 'expires': None, 'group': None, 'group_index': None, 'retries': 0, 'timelimit': [None, None], 'root_id': 'bdaa8c59-8b84-4f79-af1c-7fe34468894d', 'parent_id': None, 'argsrepr': '()', 'kwargsrepr': '{}', 'origin': 'gen3644@WIN-7483UVBHTO4', 'ignore_result': False, 'replaced_task_nesting': 0, 'stamped_headers': None, 'stamps': {}}

The delivery info for this task is:
{'exchange': '', 'routing_key': 'celery'}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\VsCodeProjects\Pastebin_hardEdition\venv\lib\site-packages\celery\worker\consumer\consumer.py", line 658, in on_task_received
    strategy = strategies[type_]
KeyError: 'tasks.cache_popular_posts'

this task #posts/tasks.py
@app.task
def cache_popular_posts():
try:
    popular_posts = Post.objects.filter(views__gt=10)
    for post in popular_posts:
        hash = post.postmeta.hash_id
        cache.add(key=hash, value=post)
except Exception as ex:
    return ex

#app/celery.py
import os
from celery import Celery


os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "Pastebin_hardEdition.settings")

app = Celery("Pastebin_hardEdition")
app.config_from_object("django.conf:settings", namespace="CELERY")
app.autodiscover_tasks()


#beats
app.conf.beat_schedule = {
    'cache-popular-post&Meta-every-30-seconds': {
        'task': 'tasks.cache_popular_posts',
        'schedule': 30.0,
    },
}
app.conf.timezone = 'UTC'

The broker is configured and connected
#app/init.py
from .celery import app as celery_app

__all__ = ("celery_app",)

#posts/apps.py
class PostsConfig(AppConfig):
default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
name = 'posts'

def ready(self):
    import posts.signals
    from . import tasks

i really need your help please

Celery does not work well on windows.

@Pycm
Can I do this on virtual linux?

Yes. You can. But couldn't find any problem in your code. My comment about windows is based on my own experience and info out there. When I tried to setup celery with django on windows, no matter what I did, I couldn't get it to work(I tried like 100s of possible methods and guides) . On official documentation it says they don't support windows. But they support Linux.

@Pycm
How can I thank you?

I made my comment as an answer. You can up vote for thanking me if you like. Thank you.

I am assuming you system is windows based on File "C:\Users\User\VsCodeProjects\Pastebin_hardEdition\venv\ line in your code.
I couldn't find any problem in your code. My comment about windows is based on my own experience and info out there.
When I tried to setup celery with django on windows, no matter what I did, I couldn't get it to work(I tried like 100s of possible methods and guides).
On official documentation it says they don't support windows. But they support Linux.
Celery support for windows
If you want windows support, you can try Dramatiq. Dramatiq has excellent windows support and django support.
Dramatiq
